# filling columns of a matrix by the values of outputs of different functions

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, matrix

I want to fill each column of an empty matrix by values resulted from different functions. I want to use many functions and so the speed is important. I have prepared a small example of what I want to do but I can't.

I have an empty matrix which I want to fill each column by values of functions' outputs. This matrix has an exact number of columns and each column has specific names:

```
mat<-matrix(ncol = 4)
colnames(mat)<-c("binomial","normal","gamma","exponential")
```

Then, considering a vector which includes some colnames of this matrix:

```
remove<-c("gamma","exponential")
```

I want to fill columns of this matrix by random values resulted from each distribution but under this circumstance that if remove object contains the name of columns of this matrix, they must be removed and not be computed.
I wrote this:

```
mat<-mat[,-which(colnames(mat) %in% remove) ]

mat[,1]<-rnbinom(10, mu = 4, size = 1)
mat[,2]<-rnorm(10)
mat[,3]<-rgamma(10, 0.001)
mat[,4]<-rexp(10)
```

The final matrix I am looking for that is something like this:

```
binomial    normal
1   -0.54948696
6   -0.53396115
1   0.69918478
13  0.92824442
0   0.03331125
```

I would be very grateful for your kind help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a method that constructs a function. The random generators are stored in a list and then the subset of them (those not in remove) are fed to `sapply`.

```
randMatGet <- function(sampleSize=10, remove=NULL) {
  randFuncs <- list("binomial"=function(x) rnbinom(x, mu=4, size=1),
                    "normal"=function(x)rnorm(x),
                    "gamma"=function(x) rgamma(x, 0.001),
                    "exponential"=function(x) rexp(x))

  sapply(randFuncs[setdiff(names(randFuncs), remove)], function(f) f(sampleSize))
}
```

Now, call the function

```
set.seed(1234)
randMatGet()
      binomial       normal         gamma exponential
 [1,]        0  0.375635612  0.000000e+00  1.45891992
 [2,]        1  0.310262167  0.000000e+00  1.43920743
 [3,]        1  0.005006950 3.099691e-294  2.76404158
 [4,]        5 -0.037630263 7.540715e-249  0.02316716
 [5,]        0  0.723976061  0.000000e+00  0.89394340
 [6,]        0 -0.496738863  0.000000e+00  3.68036715
 [7,]        0  0.011395161  0.000000e+00  2.90720399
 [8,]        4  0.009859946  9.088837e-34  0.13015222
 [9,]       10  0.678271423  0.000000e+00  0.81417829
[10,]        0  1.029563029  0.000000e+00  2.01986489
```

and then with remove

```
# reset seed for comparison
set.seed(1234)
randMatGet(remove=remove)
      binomial       normal
 [1,]        0  0.375635612
 [2,]        1  0.310262167
 [3,]        1  0.005006950
 [4,]        5 -0.037630263
 [5,]        0  0.723976061
 [6,]        0 -0.496738863
 [7,]        0  0.011395161
 [8,]        4  0.009859946
 [9,]       10  0.678271423
[10,]        0  1.029563029
```

---

To allow for adjustments of different parameters, change the function as follows. This is an example for the mu argument to `rbinom`.

```
randMatGet <- function(sampleSize=10, remove=NULL, mu=4) {
  randFuncs <- list("binomial"=function(x) rnbinom(x, mu=mu, size=1),
                    "normal"=function(x)rnorm(x),
                    "gamma"=function(x) rgamma(x, 0.001),
                    "exponential"=function(x) rexp(x))

  sapply(randFuncs[setdiff(names(randFuncs), remove)], function(f) f(sampleSize))
}
```

Now, you can do `randMatGet(mu=1)`.

Comment: Really appreciate for your time and your answer. I developed it to my work like this sapply(randFuncs[setdiff(names(randFuncs), except)], function(f) f(n,y)) and it returned list(). Is what I did wrong? @lmo

Comment: I mean that if I had two arguments like sampleSize and mu too. How would be that?

Comment: Thank you very much bro.